# Understanding multiple recursive calls built into variable assignments in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I have an object which is a binary tree, built by a recursive function. I'm trying to understand the recursive calls in this:

```
def buildDTree(sofar, todo):
    if len(todo) == 0:
        return binaryTree(sofar)
    else:
        withelt = buildDTree(sofar + [todo[0]], todo[1:])
        withoutelt = buildDTree(sofar, todo[1:])
        here = binaryTree(sofar)
        here.setLeftBranch(withelt)
        here.setRightBranch(withoutelt)
        return here
```

I don't understand the order of execution of the statements inside of the function. Specifically I don't understand the variable assignment statements and the order in which they will be assigned and what they will be assigned.

I do understand tree structure, how classes are made, and how simpler recursive functions work in python using return statements to initiate the recursion.

Tree object:

```python
class binaryTree(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.leftBranch = None
        self.rightBranch = None
        self.parent = None 
    def setLeftBranch(self, node):
        self.leftBranch = node
    def setRightBranch(self, node):
        self.rightBranch = node
    def setParent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
    def getValue(self):
        return self.value
    def getLeftBranch(self):
        return self.leftBranch
    def getRightBranch(self):
        return self.rightBranch
    def getParent(self):
        return self.parent
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

The buildDTree function is called using the following variables and assignment statement:

```
a = [6,3]
b = [7,2]
c = [8,4]
d = [9,5]

treeTest = buildDTree([], [a,b,c,d])
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. The order of execution is the order the statements appear in the file, plus any loops. What are you asking? And why don't you just put in some print statements if you're confused?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I do not agree it is unclear. One may think the question is unclear, because for most of us (experienced programmers), reading through a program flow is like reading our own native language. But for newbie programmers, it's still not a reflex and we should be there to show them the path the same way our teachers did it for us back at uni/school/forums/whatever...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, when you don't understand a code, the methodology is always the same: run the code as if you were the computer. i.e. make a table with all your variables and execute each line of code and write each variable modification down.

```
buildDTree(sofar=[], todo=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4],[9,5]]):

| sofar | todo                        |
| ----- | --------------------------- |
| `[]`  | `[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4],[9,5]]` |

len(todo) == 0 → false
withelt = buildDTree(sofar + [todo[0]], todo[1:])

    | sofar      | todo                  |
    | ---------- | --------------------- |
    | `[[6,3]]`  | `[[7,2],[8,4],[9,5]]` |

    len(todo) == 0 → false
    withelt = buildDTree(sofar + [todo[0]], todo[1:])

        | sofar            | todo            |
        | ---------------- | --------------- |
        | `[[6,3],[7,2]]`  | `[[8,4],[9,5]]` |

        len(todo) == 0 → false
        withelt = buildDTree(sofar + [todo[0]], todo[1:])

            | sofar                   | todo      |
            | ----------------------- | --------- |
            | `[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]]]`  | `[[9,5]]` |

            len(todo) == 0 → false
            withelt = buildDTree(sofar + [todo[0]], todo[1:])

                | sofar                        | todo |
                | ---------------------------- | ---- |
                | `[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4],[9,5]]`  | `[]` |

                len(todo) == 0 → true
                return binaryTree(sofar)

            | sofar                   | todo      | withelt                                       |
            | ----------------------- | --------- | --------------------------------------------- |
            | `[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]]]`  | `[[9,5]]` | `binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4],[9,5]])` |

            withoutelt = buildDTree(sofar, todo[1:])

                | sofar                  | todo |
                | ---------------------- | ---- |
                | `[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]]`  | `[]` |

                len(todo) == 0 → true
                return binaryTree(sofar)

            | sofar                   | todo      | withelt                                       | withoutelt                              |
            | ----------------------- | --------- | --------------------------------------------- | --------------------------------------- |
            | `[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]]]`  | `[[9,5]]` | `binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4],[9,5]])` | `binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]])` |

            here = binaryTree(sofar)

            | sofar                   | todo      | withelt                                       | withoutelt                              | here                                    |
            | ----------------------- | --------- | --------------------------------------------- | --------------------------------------- | --------------------------------------- |
            | `[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]]]`  | `[[9,5]]` | `binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4],[9,5]])` | `binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]])` | `binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]])` |

            here.setLeftBranch(withelt)
            here.setRightBranch(withoutelt)

            | sofar                   | todo      | withelt                                       | withoutelt                              | here                                                          |
            | ----------------------- | --------- | --------------------------------------------- | --------------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------------------- | 
            | `[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]]]`  | `[[9,5]]` | `binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4],[9,5]])` | `binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]])` | `binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]]`                        |
            |                         |           |                                               |                                         |              left=binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4],[9,5]]) |
            |                         |           |                                               |                                         |             right=binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]]))      |

            return here

        | sofar            | todo            | withelt                                                       |
        | ---------------- | --------------- | --------------------------------------------------------------|
        | `[[6,3],[7,2]]`  | `[[8,4],[9,5]]` | `binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]]`                        |
        |                  |                 |              left=binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4],[9,5]]) |
        |                  |                 |             right=binaryTree(value=[[6,3],[7,2],[8,4]]))      |

        withoutelt = buildDTree(sofar, todo[1:])

        ...
    ...
...
```

I'm not finishing because I do have work on my own, and because anyway it's better for you to complete this. I hope you've got the ideas behind this.
I know how tricky can recursion feel like when begining, but in the end, it's just a question of methodology.

HTH

Comment: ⁺¹ for being so assiduous ;-)

Comment: I've done that soooo many times at faculty :-) and it did not took me much time, thanks to [the best editor in the world](http://vim.org).

Comment: I've had a hard time withholding myself from revoking that ⁺¹ after reading that you are doing such things with _vi_.  But I managed.

Comment: As Alfe put it, thank you for taking great care. This is has been really helpful.

Comment: @Alfe do not underestimate the power of the vim (and not vi) force :-) copying/modifying/realigning the blocks were only a few keystrokes each time, I'm pretty sure emacs is the only editor that can do it as easily, but with vim I'm protecting [my carpal tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpal_tunnel_syndrome) :-)